# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в данном предложении? Он отправил ей роскошные цветы, как знак своей симпатии

Tags: пунктуация, как

Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в данном предложении?  *Он отправил ей роскошные цветы, как знак своей симпатии.*

Comment: Уважаемые участники, а где же ответы? Вопрос не такой однозначный, как можно подумать.

Answer (score 2):

1. Здесь значение **"в качестве"**? Да, очень похоже, поэтому для школьного ответа такое решение больше подойдет:

*Он отправил ей роскошные цветы **/ как знак своей симпАтии**.*

2. Но в художественном тексте я бы поставила запятую – как вариант, потому что выбор во многом зависит **от контекста**.

Значение причины здесь неочевидно? Даже если так, то это непринципиально. Я хочу представить текст в виде **двух сообщений** (с паузой и ударением на обеих частях). Это можно назвать **актуализацией оборота:**

*Он отправил ей роскошные цветЫ,// **как знак своей симпАтии**.*

3. Сравнить: *Он отправил ей роскошные цветы **как знак своей симпАтии**,// чтобы рассеять ее сомнения в этом.*

В сложном предложении оборот не обособляется, здесь ударение переходит на оборот (а пауза делается после него перед придаточным предложением).

Comment: Так не работает. Ударения не правят балом, они лишь следствие, они помогают выбрать, когда оба варианта возможны по смыслу. Если поставить ударения прежде всего, то все будут писать по-своему и будет хаос.

Comment: Каким "баллом" они не правят, я не поняла. Пожалуйста,запишите свое мнение в поле ответов и предложите свое решение.

Comment: Опечатка, одна Л. Говорю, что не следует ставить ударения прежде всего. Уже не первый раз.

Comment: Каким "баллом" они не правят, я не поняла. (Опечатка, а повторили два раза.)  А разный смысл в актуализации (подчеркивании) оборота. В простом предложении без запятой это  высказывание на тему (= рема), а в другом (с запятой) у него бОльшая нагрузка - оборот по смыслу равнозначен предложению (= что могло быть знаком его симпатии). Я сначала определила смысл, а потом поставила ударение. Пожалуйста,запишите свое мнение в поле ответов и предложите свое решение.

Comment: То просто было скопировано. Это не надёжный способ, к нему надо подходить с осторожностью. Можно поставить запятую по ударению там, где нельзя по правилам. Ну вот здесь что-то типа того. Ну и смысловая каша будет в предложениях с "как". Какая ещё актуализация? Это противоречит правилам. Опять новаторство?

Comment: А вы дайте свой ответ, без новаторства. По правилам, а? Кстати "в качестве" я уже записала в начале ответа (для школы как бы). Знала, что вы его предложите. Интуиция...

Comment: Чего это для школы? Правила Розенталя даже для редакторов и корректоров.

Comment: А что это вы взялись последнее время всё делать наоборот? Надо так, а у вас наоборот. Раньше редко было, а теперь постоянно.

Comment: Всё, закончили.  С правилом для редакторов и корректоров, а также с целевой направленностью моих действий сами разбирайтесь.