# О словах-маркерах при различении слитной и раздельной формы письма

Tags: грамотная-речь, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, сказуемые

1. **Маркеры** — это усилительные слова (условное название), они помогают нам выбрать форму написания НЕ. Слова эти названы в правилах, коротко эта информация выглядит так.

Усиление отрицания: частицы ДАЛЕКО НЕ, ОТНЮДЬ НЕ; отрицательные местоимения и наречия НИКАК НЕ, НИСКОЛЬКО НЕ и др.

Усиление утверждения: наречия степени ОЧЕНЬ, СОВЕРШЕННО и др.

Частицы СОВСЕМ НЕ, ОТНЮДЬ НЕ  используются как при усилении, так и при отрицании.

2. При отсутствии подсказок сложно на слух различить такие предложения: *Этот город **небольшой**. Этот город **не большой**.* Обычно в этом случае мы ориентируемся на смысл речи (отрицание или утверждение), но язык старается избегать неясных ситуаций.
3. Другие наречия тоже могут быть маркерами, но они **неоднозначны** (как «совсем не» и «вовсе не»). Например,  для наречий УЖЕ и ЕЩЕ получаем: *Этот город уже/еще **небольшой.** Этот город уже/еще **не большой.***
4. Слово «больше» — это тоже **неоднозначный маркер.** Сравним:

*Эта статья **больше недоступна**. Эта статья **больше** **не доступна, как раньше.***
Появляется сравнение, изменяется структура предложения — и уже надо писать НЕ раздельно.

4. Но слово «больше» **претендует на  однозначность**, многие считают, что это маркер раздельного написания. А напрасно… Ведь есть много примеров со слитным письмом «больше недоступна». С ними-то что делать? :)

**P. S.**

**Вопрос:** Слово «больше» — однозначный маркер или нет (ваше мнение)?

Пожалуйста, по возможности пишите в поле ответов. Комментарии могут не сохраниться, да и мне хотелось бы отметить хорошие ответы.

Я хочу послушать именно вас, сама я буду комментировать не все.

Спасибо.

Уважаемые участники, я принимаю ответ Александра. Там сказано **достаточно**, чтобы я составила собственное мнение по этому вопросу, хотя я и не со всеми точками зрения согласна. **Благодарю всех, кто принял участие в обсуждении.** 05.06.2023 год

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146452/discussion-on-question-by-sharon--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Олид, ну каждому свое. Пользуйтесь своими "бессбойными методами", я же вам не запрещаю. Будет у нас честное соревнование, ага? И пока, пока, совесть надо иметь.

Comment: Интонационно-структурный и семантический анализ — это очень субъективная вещь. Мой анализ мгновенно сказал о другом. Здесь железное отрицание, никогда не думал, что люди сделают такую проблему из ничего. Как же надоело доказывать, что 2 + 2 = 4.

Comment: Попробуйте с этими словами: *ненаглядный, неотразимый, необходимый, неотъемлемый, непререкаемый, неизменный, неразрывный, незыблемый, невероятный, непоколебимый* (про вас). С этими словами не получится, потому что там отрицание, а не утверждение.

Comment: Просто вы очень упрямый человек и считаете, что во всём правы. Вам даёшь кучу аргументов, но вы не хотите ничего слышать, тогда как у вас ноль аргументов, просто какие-то ощущения.

Comment: Тогда скажите прямо: что хотите писать слитно несмотря на то, что там отрицание. Это было бы честно.

Comment: И вообще, не понимаю, зачем спрашивать, если надо не правильный ответ, а подтверждение своего мнения. Этот сайт не для этого.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Читал, читал ответы и комментарии к трём связанным вопросам ([первый](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474118/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%9D%D0%95) – "виновник", [второй](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474137/%D0%9E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8) и этот), всех поощряя за стремление разобраться, – чуть не опух! Даже непонятно, куда писать своё мнение...

**Без «больше» возможны оба варианта** (избитое – утверждение отрицания или отрицание утверждения): *Статья недоступна / Статья не доступна.*
Такое же допустимо, если добавить *теперь / в настоящее время / совсем / вовсе / уже / ещё / пока*. Разница будет видна только на письме, в устной речи это невозможно уловить (только если специально не сделать акцент на ***не***).

Не знаю, является ли слово «больше» **однозначным** маркером, но я никак не могу принять слитное написание. Предложение *"Эта статья больше недоступна"* хочется продолжить, типа как *"больше непонятна, чем понятна"*. Я всегда поддерживаю Ваш, Sharon, интонационно-структурный подход (и далеко не все здесь Вас не понимают :)), но не в этот раз.

При добавлении сравнения и изменении структуры именно в данном случае **смысл не меняется** (*Эта статья больше не доступна, как раньше*).

"...Есть много примеров со слитным письмом «больше недоступна»". Ну и что? В том-то и дело – нет конкретных регламентирующих правил, нет всеми признанных способов проверки (подстановки, замены), нет обозначенного влияния этого «больше» на неглагольное сказуемое, поэтому и пишут как бог на душу положит.

[Однозначное мнение Грамоты.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=295581) вполне себе оправданно, а всем известное [розенталевское](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#): «Пишутся слитно с частицей ***не*** прилагательные, которые в сочетании с этой частицей приобретают противоположное значение (обычно такое слово можно заменить синонимом без ***не***)» – здесь не подходит именно из-за присутствия «больше».

*Вы перешли в режим выживания, а это значит, что вам **больше не доступна** сложная панель управления жизнью.* [[Картаслов.ру](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B0)]
*Нам **больше недоступна** роскошь быть в разногласиях с кем-то, сегодня мы живём на перенаселённой планете.* [[Картаслов.ру](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B0)]

Вот такое оно, **неоднозначное** слово «больше»...

P. S.: Если что-то вспомню из написанного по этой теме, то добавлю, а пока всё.

Comment: В устной речи чуть разделяется.

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий к ответу**

1. Спасибо, Александр, за честность, и именно за это **мой голос**. Вы  сделали пока только шажок (хотя и важный) в мою сторону, но вы **не на моей стороне**. Вы слышите, и вы думаете **по-другому.** Ключевое предложение мы пишем и слышим по-разному, а формальный анализ для вас еще очень много значит.

Но я не виню вас, просто так **от Системы не уйти**. Она давит на нас своим авторитетом, она не любит инакомыслящих, а послушных очень любит. Но Розенталь, мой Розенталь, он на моей стороне, что бы кто ни думал и ни говорил.

2. Оleedd (**как и многие другие**) будет счастлив прочитать ваш ответ. Я уже слышу, как он говорит: «Вот она, правда-истина, вот мудрое решение!» Ну что ж, пусть порадуется, мне не жалко — моё время еще не пришло, так что живите безмятежно. Думаю, что за ваш ответ проголосуют все, можно даже посчитать...

Процитирую окончание нашего разговора с **оleedd**:

— Почему же нельзя. Вот мне это совсем не трудно: я, к примеру, сразу определила слитную форму письма в заданном (конкретном!) предложении. Интонационно-структурный и семантический анализ вам в помощь. Если вы, конечно, умеете им пользоваться.

— Образная ерунда не подходит. Нужно чёткое, а не образное и чувственное.

После таких слов мне как бы слышится следующее: "**Чувство** языка — это **чувственный** бред". Забавно...

3. В то же время я оставляю за собой право **обозначать свои мысли свободно**, указывая как грамматический, так и интонационный варианты ответа. Оба! Раньше я старалась поменьше говорить об интонации, которая так не по душе многим (а также об индивидуальном и конкретном подходе к каждому решению).
4. И всё же я благодарна вам — **вы освободили меня от иллюзий**, от необходимости кому-то и что-то доказывать. Я хотела даже устроить конкурс по этому ответу, а теперь незачем. Я никому и ничего не должна, я свободна —  удивительное ощущение! Весело — это когда ничего не надо:

*Я — беспечный парень. **Ничего не надо**.*

*Только б слушать песни — сердцем подпевать,*

*Только бы струилась легкая прохлада,*

*Только б не сгибалась молодая стать…*

Это мое настроение (**как у Есенина**) после вашего ответа :)

Comment: Не чувственный бред, просто как сделать чёткую и, главное, надёжную инструкцию из этого? Никак! Не могу понять одного: вы не понимаете, что здесь отрицание, или хотите писать слитно несмотря на то, что здесь отрицание?

Comment: oleedd, идите знаете куда... Посмотрите вопрос с союзом КАК и напишите что-нибудь критическое. А эта тема закрыта.

Comment: Нельзя здесь посылать, это нарушает правила. А если я буду всех посылать? Может, ещё и матюкаться начнём? Нормально спросил...

Comment: Вы что, читать не умеете? Я же послала вас предложение с союзом КАК смотреть. Так что не надо меня напрасно обвинять:) Надоело же обсуждать одну и ту же тему.

Comment: Какое ещё предложение? Никак нельзя посылать! Культурно тоже нельзя. Я вот не опускаюсь до этого.

Comment: Ага, это вам только все можно... Ладно, извините  меня... А предложение вот это https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474136/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-как-в-данном-предложении-Он-отправил-ей-роскошные-цвет

Comment: Опять проблема из ничего? Там же "в качестве".

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, за всё! Кажется, вы немного (а может, слишком) преуменьшаете количество моих шажков :). Считать не буду, но едва ли наберётся и десяток из огромного числа ваших ответов, с которыми я был бы несогласен. И довольно часто интонационный принцип объединял наши мнения. А в данном случае это не формальный анализ, а семантический. Так что я на вашей стороне (по крайней мере, я так думаю).

Comment: Да, знаете... Чувство языка, и все такое... Отсюда и проблемы. Куда проще правило вспомнить.

Comment: @Sharon Как видим, чувство языка может подводить.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец "На вашей стороне"? Ну тогда и я тоже. Давайте все считать и писать по-разному, но быть на стороне друг друга. Весело.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  И вам спасибо за все. Не буду раскрывать эту тему в надежде на то, что вы и так поймете...

Comment: @Sharon Не будете раскрывать? Скорее всего, вы просто не можете этого сделать. У вас просто сбой в чувстве языка.

Comment: @oleedd  Я на стороне того, что предложения с одинаковым набором и порядком слов могут иметь разную пунктуацию. Зависит от контекста, замысла. А здесь в подавляющем большинстве случаев приходится додумывать.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение: ‟Эта статья больше не доступна, как раньше” – это плеоназм, потому что ‟больше не” подразумевает, что раньше была доступна. Я больше не бегаю по утрам = Я перестал бегать по утрам.

Тут как со словом ‟конечно”: пунктуация хаотична, так как в учебных пособиях, словарях и т. д. разница между частицей и вводным не описана качественно. В пользу этой точки зрения можно сказать то, что ни в одном словаре не написано, что ‟больше не” = ‟перестать быть” или это же другими словами, что разница с ‟сейчас” в том, что при ‟больше не” это было верным ранее. Это момент очень важен здесь.

Answer (score 0):

Просто пара примеров:

> Раньше Вася был подвержен чужому влиянию. Затем у него отняли всё. **Больше** он был
> **непоколебим**.

> Раньше Вася много ошибался. Затем ему поставили речь. **Больше** он был **безупречен**.

Сравним с *далеко* (некорректный вариант)

> Раньше Вася был подвержен чужому влиянию. Затем у него отняли всё.
> Он стал далеко не поколебим.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146462/discussion-on-answer-by-user190920--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: А если так? *Он был больше безупречен.*

Comment: Ответ Грамоты.ру.[Вопрос № 284466](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF&start=15)

Comment: @oleedd  в таком варианте возникает диссонанс из-за смысла "был больше безупречен (чем что-то)". Вы же ведь не скажете "Больше он был был безупречен, чем небезупречен". Стилистика мать ваша. А при выносе "больше" в начало исключается этот второй смысл.

Comment: Сказал бы такое... Например: *Больше он был недоступен, чем доступен.* А то, что у вас, не понимаю. С "был" чуть удалось понять (со временем), но грамматика очень ломанная. А здесь просто жуть...

Comment: Нет с явным "чем" в принципе можно и "Больше он был был безупречен, чем небезупречен"

Comment: Ну смысл дурацкий. Не представляю, когда так можно сказать. Всегда чётко ясно, безупречен или нет. Либо да, либо нет, здесь не может быть чего-то среднего. Это как: *Больше дверь была закрыта, чем открыта.*